# UBUNTU - java compiling but not executing - log4j ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar, log4j, classnotfoundexception

So I made a java program to run on my server (which executes fine on its own)..

But now I'm trying to add log4j to it.. so I add some code to my main class (just creating the logger for now), then on the server I add both my code and the log4j.jar to my parent directory (/home/ubuntu/)..

Next I go there and type:  javac -cp log4j.jar my/package/*.java my/otherpackage/*.java

That all compiles fine...

But then when I try to execute my program (i.e. java my.package.Main) I get a ClassNotFoundException for org.apache.log4j.Logger...

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? For some reason when I compile it's able to find the log4j.jar file, but when I try to execute it can't actually find it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the JAR when running, not just to compile the program.

```
java -cp log4j.jar:. MyClass
```

I suggest you use an IDE, and you can just write you program and click Run, Debug, Profile, Reformat and many other more productive things.

Comment: @matt using an IDE makes it much simpler. Some think too much simpler. ;)